# Maps package not working with R markdown but works perfectly fine with R script

Tags: r, maps, r-markdown, knitr

```
---
date: "2/10/2020"
output: html_document
---
---------------------------------------
```

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

I am using the election files from the [“Harvard  Database”](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/42MVDX).
Initially I load the necessary packages and do some data cleaning to get only the data on candidates who won the elections in each State across different years. The following code does this.

```
list.of.packages <- c("maps", "dplyr", "tidyverse", "car", "RColorBrewer")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages)) install.packages(new.packages)
data <- read.table("D:\\1976-2016-president.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",")
library(maps)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(RColorBrewer)
y <- data %>% group_by(state,year) %>% arrange(desc(candidatevotes)) %>% slice(1) %>% ungroup()
y <- data.frame(y)
y <- y %>%
  mutate(color = case_when(
    party == "republican" ~ 1,
    party == "democrat" ~ 7,
    TRUE                      ~ 3
  ))
```

Now, I plot the election results for year 2000.

```
temp <- y[y$year==2000,c("state", "state_fips","party","color")]
temp <- temp[match(paste(state.fips$fips),paste(temp$state_fips)),]
colpal <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(7, 'RdBu')
temp$quantcolors <- colpal[temp$color]
str(temp)
par(mfrow=c(1,1), mar=c(0,0,0,0))
map("state", col=temp$quantcolors, fill=TRUE)
title("Presidential election results by State in 2000")
```

However, it throws me the error:

```
Error in as_mapper(.f, ...) : argument ".f" is missing, with no default
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> withVisible -> eval -> eval -> map -> as_mapper
```

It works perfectly fine with R script. Can someone help me figure out what's happening here?

Comment: Are you sure you have `library(maps)` in the rmarkdown document? What if you explicitly used `maps::map()`. It sounds like you are accidentally using the `purrr` `map()` function instead. I'm surprised the script version works. Does it work in a new, fresh R session?

Comment: @MrFlick Using maps::map() works. I did use library(maps) in the markdown document. Not sure why that is not working. Thanks.

Comment: *"Not sure why that is not working."* You load `tidyverse` (which includes `purrr`) *after* you load `maps`, thereby masking `maps::map` with `purrr::map` (if you look carefully in a terminal, `tidyverse` should give a conflict warning).

Answer (score 0):

The code works perfectly fine when explicitly calling maps library:

```
temp <- y[y$year==2000,c("state", "state_fips","party","color")]
temp <- temp[match(paste(state.fips$fips),paste(temp$state_fips)),]
colpal <- RColorBrewer::brewer.pal(7, 'RdBu')
temp$quantcolors <- colpal[temp$color]
str(temp)
par(mfrow=c(1,1), mar=c(0,0,0,0))
maps::map("state", col=temp$quantcolors, fill=TRUE)
title("Presidential election results by State in 2000")
```